# ORCAD: How to automatically change net alias when cut paste circuit blocks

Tags: schematics, orcad, schematic

I have couple orcad capture schematic design-related query. I'm on Orcad Capture CIS 17.4

**First**
When I cut and paste a circuit block, the net alias rename the same.

[image: Cut pasted and net alias remain same]

Is there an automatic way to have the net alias change when I cut paste

[image: Net alias automatically renamed]

**Second**
Is there a quick way to rename a net alias across all the schematic pages. To fix typos etc.

Comment: I doubt there is. A label needs to stay put, as placed by the user. The program cannot read minds whether you want it to be automatically incremented, or just copied. It considers it to be a user-mode intervention and so it keeps it unchanged. But I don't have OrCAD and, maybe, there is a way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

A coworker helped me out.
For first,
Instead of copy, he suggested to do a CTRL + left click and drag. The nets get automatically renumbered.

[image]

For second,
he suggested using Tools>>Utilities>>Find and Replace. That did the trick. he seems to be very aggressive, and finds and replaces a string even when its a substring.

Comment: Welp... this just changed my life. Thanks!

Comment: Nice feature. What happens when you don't have numbers, e.g. `BATT`? Or when the numbers are not the lasat characters, e.g. `OUT_1_A`? Also, you can accept your own answer (but not upvote it).

Comment: Yes it only limited to net aliases ending with a number like TEST1 or TEST_1. It didn't work for BATT or even OUT_1_A